# How to solve the problem with Facebook Login restriction due to violation of the policy

Tags: facebook

Now, My Facebook Login API has been restrict with the following message from Facebook:

> Your app is violating the following Platform Terms or Developer
> Policies: Developer Policy 1.2: Build an app that is stable and easily
> navigable.Some common violations of this policy include:
>
> - Broken Facebook integration (e.g. broken share, like or comment functionality)
> - Broken user experience in the app (e.g. app has broken links or user interface failures)

I still have no clue what I have done wrong on my Facebook API though.

How can I make a change on Facebook API to solve this kind of problem that causes Facebook to restrict by Facebook Login API.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this? How can you contact to Facebook developer?

Answer (score 1):

That may be due to the following reason:

> Facebook periodically reviews the websites and applications which are
> on it. Your application is in its review process currently. We are
> required to test the Facebook login functionality in order to conclude
> the review in totality. However, we are unable to do so.
>
> Unfortunately, we have not been able to locate a Facebook integration
> (Login, Share, and Like) on your submitted platform. To help us
> conclude the review process, could you kindly share the details
> regarding the location of a Facebook integration and how to navigate
> to it on your website URL.
>
> This review is essential to Facebook as we want to offer the best
> experience to users as well as developers like yourself. Please help
> us in bringing your application into compliance by working with us.
> Alternatively, you could aid us by sending us credentials of a test
> user who is already registered and connected to an FB account within
> the app. You can get all the information related to creating a test
> user here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users.

Most people get this response in further detail. You can check the Facebook button on the given URL in the Facebook app.
If Facebook button URL is different and the URL mentioned in the Facebook app is different then you should reply to them and explain it.